# Get file from folder based on pattern criteria and exceptions

Tags: vba, foreach

Cannot figure out how to implement the following use case.

I pass a folder and criterias (seperated by a ";") to a function and retrieve a file if criterias were matched.
This is working quite well, but I have an exception:

If the criteria pattern in the first position is "ABC", there are multiple files which could match the search pattern.
My goal is to prioritize the finding in a sense that a file containing "RD_" should have a higher prioritization than a file which contains the string "SD_".

Hint:
If a file has the string "RD_" inside and matches also the other criterias, then the function can stop.
If a file has the string "SD_" inside and matches also the other criterias, then the function should not stop and still loop all files within the folder and try to find a file matching all criterias AND "RD_".

Hope you can help me further.

```
Sub getTargetFile()
    Debug.Print getInputFilePath("D:\", "ABC;11111")
End Sub


Function getInputFilePath(inputDirectoryToScanForFile, filenameCriteria) As String

    Dim vSplitCriteria:  vSplitCriteria = Split(filenameCriteria, ";")  '   Split the criteria into pieces and put them into an array

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sFoundFile As String

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(inputDirectoryToScanForFile)

    Dim blnCorrectFiles As Boolean
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files     '   Loop through each file in folder
        blnCorrectFiles = True          '   assume the current file is correct
        'Debug.Print oFile.Name
        For i = LBound(vSplitCriteria) To UBound(vSplitCriteria)            '   Loop through all file name criteria
            If Not InStr(1, UCase(oFile.Name), UCase(vSplitCriteria(i))) > 0 Then   '   check whether criteia matched
                blnCorrectFiles = False
            End If
            If blnCorrectFiles = False Then Exit For
        Next i
        If blnCorrectFiles = True Then     '    if all criteria are matched, otherwise it was set to false inbetween the above loop
            sFoundFile = oFile.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oFile

    If blnCorrectFiles = True Then
        getInputFilePath = inputDirectoryToScanForFile & sFoundFile
    Else
        getInputFilePath = ""
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: Side note: Passing multiple criteria inside the same variable is a bad practice and is unnecessary. VBA already supports passing  an array as an argument or you can pass an array of parameters ( as in `getInputFilePath( Directory, mycriteria1, mycriteria2, mycriteria3)`. See [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays) and a tutorial [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/paramarray.htm).

Comment: usually it's not the case how I do it, but since the criterias are listed inside one cell I took this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check for RD_ first and then if nothing is found, check for SD_. Which sounds like you just need to run the function twice. Trying to mix and match inside the function would be difficult to generalize and only make things messy.

```vb
Sub Prioritize()
    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = "D:\"
    
    Dim Criteria As String
    Criteria = "ABC;11111"
    
    Dim fPath As String
    fPath = getInputFilePath(Directory, "RD_;" & Criteria)
    
    If fPath = "" Then fPath = getInputFilePath(Directory, "SD_;" & Criteria)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I was blind trying to solve the problem inside a function, but you're right, it would less messy to just run the function twice, if in the first time nothing was found. thank you!